# Cypress ReferenceError: input is undefined (Cypress, Cucumber, POM)

Tags: cucumber, cypress, pom.xml

I'm struggling to find the reason for this:
I'm using Cypress, Cucumber and POM approach.
This is my POM file `LoginPage.js`

```
class LoginPage {

    get usernameInput() {
        return cy.get('input[name="email"]');
    }
    get passwordInput() {
        return cy.get('input[name="password"]');
    }
    get submitBT() {
        return cy.get('button[type="submit"]');
    }

    loginToCMS() {
        cy.visit('https://example.com')
        usernameInput.type('admin@admin.com');
    }
}

export default new LoginPage
```

Then I try to call loginToCMS() function in another `loginSteps.js` file:

```
import { Given, When, Then, And } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps'
import LoginPage from '../../pages/LoginPage'

Given('user is logged in CMS', () => {
   LoginPage.loginToCMS(); 
})
```

When run feature file, I get an error: `Reference Error: usernameInput is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usernameInput` is a function on the LoginPage class, so you have to use `this` to call it.

```js
class LoginPage {
  get usernameInput() {
    return cy.get('input[name="email"]');
  }
  ...
  loginToCMS() {
    cy.visit('https://example.com');
    this.usernameInput.type('admin@admin.com');
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking it's a getter not a function, but the principle is the same.